# Magento 2: how to add version in your assets (i.e ...sample.js?v=1 and ...sample.css?v=2)?

Tags: magento2

I want to create a config where I can put asset version. This will be inserted on every included asset (particularly CSS and JS) as a query string. Example: sample.css?v=1

Comment: Have you tried using the built in feature for versioning static content? ‘Stores>Configuration>Developer>Sign Static Files’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to answer this (my own question).

@PMclain is correct.

As of Magento version 2.1.6 and above, static versioning is supported. Static versioning is a feature in Magento which create prefixes using subfolders in pub/static folder. If you are in Magento 2.1.6 below, I suggest that you upgrade it. Make sure to read upgrade guides carefully.

Example:

from example.com/pub/static/frontend.. 
to
example.com/pub/static/**version1492289532**/frontend..

You can learn more about here: https://medium.com/@maxpronko/magento-2-static-content-lesson-learned-7bf8e796f682